# Problems with debugging in my flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart

I went to check another code so I closed my app and started another one. However, when I went to reopen my app that I'm developing, it doesn't open anymore! I restarted the PC and the like and I don't see any logic in this bug. When I create a new app, it works normally but when I add it to main.dart the app just stops. Can you help me?

Below is the error that appears:

```
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I don't see the logic in this bug, I'm starting on DART/Flutter